# How to compute log fold change for a linear mixed effect model?

Tags: mixed-model

Suppose i am performing a test using the `lme` function, on some ecology data, i.e. count data. Say this is the formula:

`a_model <- lme(fixed=Abundance~Treatment*TimePoint, random=~1|Plot, data=some_data)`

Say i do this for many taxa (and yes, i know i have to correct for multiple testing). How do i compute the log fold change for those taxa that are significant?

I was reading something regarding the limma package ([link](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/59037/)) and MAST ([link](https://github.com/RGLab/MAST/issues/147)) which both suggest that i should look into the coefficients of the model:

```
> coef(a_model)
   (Intercept) TreatmentW  TimePointOne  TimePointTwo  TreatmentW:TimePointOne
s6   -157.4089  -24.77521      14.47133      13.03256                 12.82662
s3   -151.2558  -24.77521      14.47133      13.03256                 12.82662
s4   -157.9029  -24.77521      14.47133      13.03256                 12.82662
s2   -134.1777  -24.77521      14.47133      13.03256                 12.82662
s1   -142.5115  -24.77521      14.47133      13.03256                 12.82662
s5   -154.3185  -24.77521      14.47133      13.03256                 12.82662
    TreatmentW:TimePointTwo
s6                 22.63591
s3                 22.63591
s4                 22.63591
s2                 22.63591
s1                 22.63591
s5                 22.63591
```

But then what? Should i just compute the log2 of, say, the `abs(TreatmentW)` column to get the fold change?

`log2(abs(coef(a_model)[, "TreatmentW"]))`

But then i will have one fold change for each *Plot* so...how to treat this? Any ideas?

EDIT - some more context

What i need to perform is differential abundant analysis. I know there are many algorithms that do perform the analysis i need ([edgeR](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/edgeR.html), [deseq2](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DESeq2.html), [ANCOM-BC](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ANCOMBC.html)...) but for some reasons ANCOM-BC (which should be the way to go because it was designed for microbiomes) is having issues with parameter estimation (not ANCOM-BC directly but the `lmer` function within the algorithm). I think this happens because i need to fit a model but i don't have enough samples (n=36, but then n_ctrl=18 and n_treat=18 if i compare control vs treatment, then it goes down to n_ctrl_t1=6, n_ctrl_t2=6, n_ctrl_t3=6, and same for treated samples) to correctly estimate the parameters for the statistics. I also simplified the model trying to include only on fixed effect but it still does not work so yes, i don't know. Surprisingly, Deseq2 works, but it's true that it does not handle random effects so i am only testing treatment and timepoint.

So, i thought to perform a simpler analysis using mixed effect models to test if any taxa has significant differences between control and treated samples (fixed effect), considering the effect of different sampling times (fixed effect) and different sampling sites (random effect).

Comment: If you are evaluating count outcomes then you should not be using a linear regression of the type you show. A Poisson (or quasi-Poisson or negative binomial) model is more appropriate; the default log link used in such models directly provides results in a natural log scale, which can be converted to a $\log_2$ scale if you want.

Comment: alright, will have a look, thanks!

Comment: what if i subset the counts table by taxa? in that case i think i shouldn't have zero inflated data. i could perform the test for all taxa, then adjust p-values, right?

Comment: It's hard to say, as you haven't provided much information about the study, the nature of your data, or the hypothesis you are testing. Sometimes it's better to do one large model including everything you measured (all taxa, here). Zero inflation is something that can be dealt with, if it ends up being an issue.

Comment: thanks for your answers. i'll add some info in the original question, just to clarify the context.